# KeyNotFoundException when a Key with the requested value exists in VB.NET ASP.NET 2.0 Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, asp.net-2.0, keynotfoundexception

[image: Debug Session Image]
The ValueList variable is defined as Dictionary(Of String, String)

The watch values captured show the data (tmpData) has a value of "1".

The ValueList is defined such that the replacement value for "1" is "Project Resource" as can be seen form the expansion of the SSGCol.ValueList Watch variable.

However, when I try to access the value I receive a KeyNotFoundException

I have done this sort of thing thousands of times in the past, but for some reason today I cannot get it to work.  I must be missing something really obvious and need someone to take a fresh look and give me a slap when they see my obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there are some unprintable characters in the string.  Try comparing the bytes in the strings, for instance:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tmpData)
```

Comment: Good call Steven. The key somehow had a stray line feed character before the "1" in the dictionary key value. the bytes showed the key as {"10", "0", "49", "0"} and the tmpData as {"49", "0"}

Comment: Yay!  I hate those kind of brick-wall problems that just leave you scratching your head.

Comment: Thanks again Steven, that is another tool added to my toolbox now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
    Dim lst As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    lst.Add("1", "Test")

    Dim tmpS As String = String.Empty
    lst.TryGetValue("1", tmpS)
```